# Laravel 5.6 : Call to a member function getRealPath() on string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estoy intentando enviar un email desde mi proyecto de **Laravel**.  Al entrar en el store obtengo este error:

> Call to a member function getRealPath() on string

El email se envia con un archivo adjunto, cuando lo envio sin tomar en cuenta el archivo adjunto se envia bien.

Aqui coloco el controlador:

```
<?php

namespace proyecto\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Storage;
use Mail;
use Config;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class EmailController extends Controller {
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

     /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
     public function index() {       
         return view('administracion.email.email')
                ->with('method','POST');
     }

     public function store(Request $request) {     
         $data = array(
             'destino'    => $request['destino'],
             'asunto'     => $request['asunto'],
             'contenido'  => $request['contenido'],
             'a_file'     => $request['a_file']
         );

         Mail::send('administracion.email.email_body', $data, function($message) use ($data) {
             $message->to($data['destino']);
             $message->subject($data['asunto']);
             $message->from(Config::get('mail.username'));
             $message->attach($data['a_file']->getRealPath(), array(
                 'as'    => 'a_file' . $data['a_file']->getClientOriginalExtension(),
                 'mime'  => $data['a_file']->getMimeType()) 
             );
         });
     return Redirect::to('email'); 
     }
}
```

Comment: el $data['a_file'] te está llegando como un string y no como un objeto, po lo cual no puedes llamar una función a una string, tienes que mirar porqué te llega como string y no como objeto.

Answer (score 0):

te esta interpretando el $request['a_file'] como la cadena, en lugar de un objeto file, por eso te dice que llamas al metodo getRealPath() en una cadena.

Buscando en el manual de laravel https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files, dice que para cojer un archivo desde el request debes acceder de esta manera:

```
$file = $request->file('photo');
```

Por tanto, tu codigo deberia ser algo como esto:

```
 $data = array(
     'destino'    => $request['destino'],
     'asunto'     => $request['asunto'],
     'contenido'  => $request['contenido'],
     'a_file'     => $request->file('a_file')
 );
```

Con ello ahora $data['a_file'] deberia ser un objeto file que tendra su metodo getRealPath()

Destacar que, en caso de que te devuelva null, volveras a tener un error, esta vez de llamar a getRealPath() en null. Te recomiendo que pongas en un if el codigo de insercion del archivo:

```
if(!null($data['a_file']) {
  $message->attach(
      $data['a_file']->getRealPath(), 
      array(
          as'=> 'a_file'.$data['a_file']->getClientOriginalExtension(),
      'mime'  => $data['a_file']->getMimeType()
     ) 
  );
}
```

Comment: Lo cambie como indicaste, pero obtengo el mismo error. De hecho haciendo un "dd"  en $data['a_file'] ahora obtengo Null.

Comment: estaba editando la respuesta. Revisalo, tambien te añado lo del caso del null.